# Storing and Accessing variable/values in amibroker afl code

Tags: amibroker

I am inputting few values with Param functions.

1. selecting timeframe
2. Assigning period to the selected timeframe.

Now if i want to store the timeframe and corresponding period to a array and later in the code if to retrieve it, how do i do it in amibroker AFL?

say like storing data similar to below at start of program

```
setting    period[in3minutes] = 10;
setting    period[in5minutes] = 20;
setting    period[in10minutes] = 30;
```

and at end the getting assigned data

```
period1 = period[in3minutes];
period2 = period[in5minutes];
period3 = period[in10minutes];
```

Here is the sample code of setting the data with Param.

```
    swing_tf            = ParamList  ("Custom TimeFrames0 (default is 15min)", "in1Minute|in3Minute|in5Minute|in15Minute|in25Minute|in30Minute|in45Minute|inHourly|in75Minute|in90Minute|inDaily|inWeekly|inMonthly", 3);
    swing_period        = Param      ("Custom TimeFrames0 Periods", 20, 1, 200, 1);
    swing_tf1           = ParamList  ("Custom TimeFrames1 (default is 30min)", "in1Minute|in3Minute|in5Minute|in15Minute|in25Minute|in30Minute|in45Minute|inHourly|in75Minute|in90Minute|inDaily|inWeekly|inMonthly", 5);
    swing_period1       = Param      ("Custom TimeFrames1 Periods", 20, 1, 200, 1);
    swing_tf2           = ParamList  ("Custom TimeFrames2 (default is hourly)", "in1Minute|in3Minute|in5Minute|in15Minute|in25Minute|in30Minute|in45Minute|inHourly|in75Minute|in90Minute|inDaily|inWeekly|inMonthly", 7);
    swing_period2       = Param      ("Custom TimeFrames2 Periods", 20, 1, 200, 1);
    swing_tf3           = ParamList  ("Custom TimeFrames3 (default is 90min)", "in1Minute|in3Minute|in5Minute|in15Minute|in25Minute|in30Minute|in45Minute|inHourly|in75Minute|in90Minute|inDaily|inWeekly|inMonthly", 9);
    swing_period3       = Param      ("Custom TimeFrames3 Periods", 20, 1, 200, 1);
```

Thanks in advance for your time in helping me out with this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try a matrix,

```
m = Matrix(1, 4, Null);

m[0][0] = in1Minute;        // 1 Minute
m[0][1] = in1Minute * 3;    // 3 Minute
m[0][2] = in5Minute;        // 5 Minute
m[0][3] = in15Minute;       // 15 Minute

p = [0][2] // in5Minute
```

It can be initialized easier if you are just looking for a set of constants.

```
m = MxFromString("{{10,20,30,40}}");
```